# How to exclude a list of full directory paths in find command on Solaris

Tags: shell, scripting, find, solaris

*(Duplicated from Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854975/how-to-exclude-a-list-of-full-directory-paths-in-find-command-on-solaris)*

I have a very specific need to find unowned files and directories in Solaris using a script, and need to be able to exclude full directory paths from the find because they contain potentially thousands of unowned files (and it's normal because they are files hosted on other servers). I don't even want find to search in those directories as it will hang the server (cpu spiking to 99% for a long time), therefore piping the find results in egrep to filter out those directories is not an option.

I know I can do this to exclude one of more directories by name:

`find / -mount -local \( -type d -a \( -name dir1 -o -name dir2 -o dir3 \) \) -prune -o \( -nouser -o -nogroup \) -print`

However, this will match dir1 and dir2 anywhere in the directory structure of any directories, which is **not** what I want at all.

I want to be able to prevent find from even searching in the following directories (as an example):

```
/opt/dir1
/opt/dir2
/var/dir3/dir4
```

And I still want it to find unowned files and directories in the following directories:

```
/opt/somedir/dir1
/var/dir2
/home/user1/dir1
```

I have tried using regex in the -name arguments, but since find only matches 'name' against the basename of what it finds, I can't specify a path. Unfortunately, Solaris's find does not support GNU find options such as -wholename or -path, so I'm kind of screwed.

My goal would be to have a script with the following syntax:

`script.sh "/path/to/dir1,/path/to/dir2,/path/to/dir3"`

How could I do that using find and standard sh scripting (/bin/sh) on Solaris (5.8 and up)?

Comment: Just by the way, you could easily install [GNU findutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/), it's [in](http://pkgsrc.se/sysutils/findutils) [pkgsrc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkgsrc) which supports Solaris - since it would save you some work.

Comment: I know, but the servers we support are not ours, and we can't install anything without the approval of our clients, and some would refuse changing core binaries such as _find_. We have hundreds of servers that have Solaris, and none is configured exactly the same. That's why we need to use only POSIX binaries.

Comment: Since the implementation(s) of `find` do not support `-path` test, you can simulate it using `-exec test "{}" = "/path/to/exclude" \; -prune`. The `{}` should be expanded to full path name.

Comment: Humm... I tested it using this command on RHEL 5.6 (I don't have access to Solaris from home):

`find / -mount \( -type d -a \( -exec test "{}" = /dev \; -o -exec test "{}" = "/proc" \; -o -exec test "{}" = "/tmp/test" \; \) \) -prune -o \( -nouser -o -nogroup \) -print`

It worked, but it took a *lot* more time to run. I was monitoring CPU usage while the find was running and it was not going over 27%, which is not so bad, but I only have 3 tests in my condition. I wonder how bad it would get when there's more...

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz: You should post your comment as an answer so I can vote on it if it turns out this is the only option. That way you'll get some rep! You deserve it!

Comment: Isn't it possible to migrate a post from SO? Just duplicating it seems a bit annoying ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't match files by full path with [Solaris `find`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9ft/index.html), but you can match files by inode. So use `ls -i` to generate a list of inodes to prune, then call `find`. This assumes that there aren't so many directories you want to prune that you'd go over the command line length limit.

```
inode_matches=$(ls -bdi /opt/dir1 /opt/dir2 /var/dir3/dir4 |
                sed -e 's/ *\([0-9][0-9]*\) .*/-inum \1 -o/')
find / -xdev \( $inode_matches -nouser -o -nogroup \) -prune -o -print
```

An alternative approach would be to use a Perl or Python script and roll your own directory traversal. Perl ships with a `find2perl` script that can get you started with the `File::Find` module. In Python, see the `walk` function in the `os.path` module.

Comment: +1 Ahh... Better. As always... ;)

Comment: Don't have enough rep to upvote yet, or I would have... sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Since the implementation(s) of find do not support `-path` test, you can simulate it using `-exec test "{}" = "/path/to/exclude" \; -prune` (the `{}` should be expanded to full path name).

This, unfortunately,  will take more time than "pure" find, since the `test` program will get executed in each run. So make sure to optimize the tests as much as you can - for example, check which of these two runs faster:

```
 -exec test "{}" = "/dev" \; -o -exec test "{}" = "/proc" \; -o -exec test "{}" = "/tmp/test" \;
```

or

```
 -exec test "{}" = "/dev" -o "{}" = "/proc" -o "{}" = "/tmp/test" \;
```

I think the latter should be faster overall, because the `test` program is executed only once.

<sub>Note: You don't need the `-a`'s for and-logic; this is implied by default. Same goes for `-print` at the end.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the details! I will test it out and try to optimize the test condition as best as I can to compensate. I will accept the answer since there's really no better alternative short of installing GNU findutils on every Solaris server we support (which is out of the question). I will look into a Perl alternative too, but I'm not sure which will be the fastest...

Comment: Could you do me a favor and post the same answer on the Stack Overflow version of this post as well? The link is on top. Would be much appreciated!

Comment: Tested both variants of the exec condition, here are the results: using multiple -o in the same test = much faster, but 25% more CPU usage in average (eye-balled it using top). Using multiple tests = less CPU usage, but MUCH longer to run. Seems either way, there's a performance hit compared to the built-in find operations.

Comment: Such increased CPU usage is seems not so bad if it runs faster - the machine does more analyzing instead of I/O. This *might* be even beneficial to responsiveness. To make sure your script does not interfere too much with the rest of system, run it using `nice`.

Comment: Just so you're on the loop too, my other post on Stack Overflow got a better answer. Using inodes with ls -bdi, and then -num in the find. It's POSIX compliant and will work on old systems. This is much faster than using -exec test... It's nice to know both options however! Could come in handy in the future.

Comment: ..sorry, I meant -inum, not -num